# Hide Records based on field values

Tags: jasper-reports

we are currently using iReport, we have a requirement to only display records on a report with discrepancies between fields. To complete this report I will need to hide records that have matching values in two fields. As far as I am aware I can use a print when expression but this is only to hide fields alone not entire records. What would be the process to do this?

I have a boolean created within iReports with the following Expression:

`$F{Value1}.equals($F{Value2})`

I need to use a print when Expression tag to NOT display the record if this boolean is true.

I've tried looking at the reverse

`if(!$F{Value1}.equals($F{Value2}))` but iReport doesn't seem to like that.

Comment: Print when expression works perfect. Could you post the sample?

Comment: @AlexK
Example: '<reportElement x="400" y="41" width="100" height="20" uuid="24d04b0a-4463-4250-80a1-1ad508cdf217"/>
    <text><![CDATA[GrossWeightKgValue]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <staticText>
    <reportElement x="500" y="41" width="100" height="20" uuid="0ef95c80-39f8-4832-9308-714fe9ea0832"/>
    <text><![CDATA[VGMWeightKgValue]]></text>
   </staticText>
   <staticText>'
If VGMWeightKGValue = GrossWeightKgValue then hide record.

hope this gives you more info.

Comment: @AlexK <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{VGMWeightKgValue}.equals($F{GrossWeightKgValue})]]></variableExpression>

Comment: This snippet is not relevant. You should post the simple test (you can edit the original post) to check the problem

Comment: `if(!$F{Value1}.equals($F{Value2})) but iReport doesn't seem to like that.` - The right expression is: `!$F{Value1}.equals($F{Value2})`

Comment: @AlexK Cheers I have then included it into a parameter with which now looks like this: ' <parameter name="VGM=Gross" class="java.lang.Boolean" isForPrompting="false">
<printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{Print When Expression}]]></printWhenExpression>
 </parameter>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a ! before the expression like this:

```
!$F{Value1}.equals($F{Value2})
```

This says: Don't print when the Value1 equals Value2, which I think is what you want.

Your second expression with "if" in it does not work, because it's not a valid boolean expression. An if statement is a control structure and does not have a return value.